# python selenium element located but not clickable - timeout exception

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to make a register bot with fake mail adresses by mohmal.

i can take e mail but when verification code come to the inbox, i cannot be able to open inbox

the service: https://www.mohmal.com/tr/inbox

after i got e mail, i tried following code to dive in:

```
try:
    control = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='inbox-table']/tbody"))
    )
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='inbox-table']/tbody").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    print("to see mail, inbox body is clicked")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("failed to click")

#verification code
vfCode = ""
    try:
        control = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, vfCode_CSS))
        )
        vfCode = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(vfCode_CSS).text
        time.sleep(1)
        print(vfCode )
        print("vf code copied")
    except:
        print("failed to copy")
```

and error code is just:

***Message:***

nothing more

Comment: usually `<tbody>` is not clickable. Why do you try to click it? Maybe you should find some element inside `<tbody>` which will be clickable - ie. `<a>`

Comment: @furas i didnt know that, after you said, i changed my xpath as 
"//*[@id="inbox-table"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a" and nothing changed

Answer (score -1):

does the code comes inside the subject or only inside the e-mail? can you see it without clicking it?

Comment: only inside the e-mail, i need to click this "//*[@id='inbox-table']/tbody" XPATH

Comment: try this: 
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[6]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]").click()
time.sleep(2)
so this first code clicks the subject, after that you have to get the code from inside email

Comment: same mistake, it's just not clicking the element, and waits for some time then, TimeoutException occurs. I'm using selenium for some time but i didnt see anything like this...

Comment: let me check it

Comment: btw i changed my xpath as "//*[@id="inbox-table"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a" after @furas said in the answer comment, but same problem agaiiin

Comment: its a iframe, you need to switch to it, I am working on it I will let you know with the solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221224/discussion-between-umut-pinarbasi-and-fatih-tuz).